# Input checkbox only in order

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution on how to set a selection rule in the input checkbox which will allow to select 3 elements but only in the right order.

Let's assume that we have several check boxes eg ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6.
The user can only mark three but only one by one.

ch1 + ch2 + ch3 - it is ok

ch3 + ch4 + ch5 - is is ok

**ch2** + ch4 + ch5 - it is not ok

ch1 + ch2 + **ch4** - it is not ok

I know how to limit:

```
$('#Miesiac :checkbox').change(function () {
    var $checks=$(this).closest('#Miesiac').find(':checkbox:checked');
    if ($checks.length > 3) {
        this.checked=false;
    }
});
```

But how to give the rule one by one. Do You have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You mean user can only check up to 3 chx consecutively? ex. 1,2,3 or 2,3,4?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Some ideas: if you have only a few checkboxes, disable all except the entry points (the ones that can be selected first) then with a bunch of `if else`s enable the next checkboxes that can be selected. If you want to do it properly, design a Finite State Machine

Comment: A good idea. e.g. If the user selects box # 3 then only # 2 and # 4 remain and the rest is switched off. then if the user selects # 4 then # 5 will be included because he can still choose # 2 or # 5 ...
Ali Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the checkboxes an Id or Attribute that is consecutive like it looks like you are doing...
ch1, ch2, ch3 etc...

In the change event, you have scope of this to the checkbox that is currently being checked/unchecked. Parse the ID or attribute from this of the checkbox.

```
var theId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Parse the number of the checkbox from that id string with a simple string check. Then you can check the checked state of the checkboxes one increment above and one below the current checkbox. I'm making this code more verbose than needed just for clarity sake.

```
theId.replace('ch','');
theId++; //For one above
$('ch'+theId).checked;
```

or

```
$('ch'+theId).attr('checked');
```

There you go now you should have the checked state of one above and if it's invalid you can set a error state variable. Do the same for one below and you can do whatever validation break, message, page event intercept or whatever you need from there. There is probably 20 different ways to do this, this is one idea.